# kendo-ui mobile loader - how to change color of loader

Tags: kendo-ui

I am attempting to change the background color of the loader included in the "flat" skin. I attempted the following that was suggested in the forums, but the background color remains the flat teal color.

```
.km-loader:before {
   background: Red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple different loaders, and the CSS seems to be platform specific, but this one is re-colored for ios7.

```
.km-ios7 .km-loading,
.km-ios7 .km-loading:after,
.km-ios7 .km-loading:before {
    color: #f00;
    box-shadow: 16px 0 rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 16px 0 rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
}

.km-ios7 .km-loading,
.km-ios7 .km-loader .km-loading-left {
    background: #f00;
    box-shadow: 16px 0 rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 16px 0 rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
}
```

[Example on Kendo Dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/IboVi](http://dojo.telerik.com/IboVi)

Comment: Thanks, Spike. I wasn't specifying the theme in the selector - .km-flat .km-loader:before

Answer (score 0):

I got the styles working by specifying the theme I am using in the selector

```
.km-flat .km-switch-handle,
.km-flat .k-slider-selection,
.km-flat .km-switch-background {
  color: #105fac;
}
.km-flat .km-rowinsert,
.km-flat .km-state-active,
.km-flat .km-scroller-pull,
.km-flat .km-loader:before,
.km-flat .k-slider-selection,
.km-flat .km-touch-scrollbar,
.km-flat .km-pages .km-current-page,
.km-flat .k-slider .k-draghandle,
.km-flat .k-slider .k-draghandle:hover,
.km-flat .km-tabstrip .km-state-active,
.km-flat .km-scroller-refresh.km-load-more,
.km-flat .km-popup .k-state-hover,
.km-flat .km-popup .k-state-focused,
.km-flat .km-popup .k-state-selected,
.km-flat .km-actionsheet > li > a:active,
.km-flat .km-actionsheet > li > a:hover,
.km-flat .km-actionsheet > li > .km-state-active,
.km-flat li.km-state-active .km-listview-link,
.km-flat li.km-state-active .km-listview-label,
.km-flat .km-listview-label input[type=radio]:checked,
.km-flat .km-listview-label input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  background: #105fac;
}
.km-flat .km-filter-wrap > input:focus {
  border-color: #105fac;
}
```